# how to display image retrieved from mysql on JFrame

Tags: java, swing

I am facing a problem in displaying image that retrieved from database on JFrame. Here is the that i will use,
      .........

```
     try
               {
               Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/studio","root","");  
            Statement st=con.createStatement();   
            ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery( "select  image  from photo_instn where cust_id='2'") ;
            while(rs.next()) 
            {
            byte[] imagedata = rs.getBytes("image") ;
            Image img = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage(imagedata);
            ImageIcon icon =new ImageIcon(img);
            JLabel lPhoto = new JLabel(icon) ;
            setLayout(null);                              // BYTES TO IMAGE                                                                      
            System.out.println("Inside");
            System.out.println(lPhoto);
            this.add(lPhoto) ;
            lPhoto.setBounds(200,20,300,400); 
  }
}
```

---

This code has no problem.but image not displayed on frame...
Please help me for solving this problem....

Comment: Please use the code formatting.

Answer (score 2):

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.sql.*;

import javax.swing.*;

public class DisplayImage extends JFrame {

Connection connection = null;
PreparedStatement statement = null;

ResultSet result;

public DisplayImage() {
    super("Image Display");
    setSize(600, 600);
    connection = getConnection();
    try { // table name:image and second image is field name
        statement = connection
                .prepareStatement("select image from  image where id = 1");
        result = statement.executeQuery();

        byte[] image = null;
        while (result.next()) {
            image = result.getBytes("image");

        }
        Image img = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage(image);
        ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(img);
        JLabel lPhoto = new JLabel();
        lPhoto.setIcon(icon);
        add(lPhoto);

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    setVisible(true);
}

public Connection getConnection() {
    Connection connection = null;

    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
                // user name:root and password:blank
                "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/insertRetriveImages", "root",
                "");

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error Occured While Getting the Connection: - "
                + e);
    }
    return connection;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new DisplayImage();
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try adding `this.setVisible(true)` to your code after

> this.add(lPhoto) ;

Answer (score 1):

```
 Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection  con= DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/vodafonecare","root","root");
            PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement("select * from photo");
            ResultSet rs=ps.executeQuery();
            if(rs.next()){
                rs.next();
                 rs.next();
            Blob b=rs.getBlob(3);
            byte bt[]=b.getBytes(1,(int)b.length());
             Image img = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage(bt);
             photoL.setIcon(new ImageIcon(img));
```

Answer (score 0):

1 Retrieve `byte[]` from DB as you did in your code then

```
InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(imageInByte);
BufferedImage bImageFromConvert = ImageIO.read(in);
```

2 Represent that image on JFrame

```
boolean Graphics.drawImage(Image img, 
                           int x, int y,
                           ImageObserver observer);
```

**Also See**

- [Drawing an Image](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/drawimage.html)

Answer (score 0):

We don't know the context of how this code is used.

Generally after adding/removing a component from a GUI you need to use:

```
panel.revalidate();
panel.repaint();
```